# Sending/Receiving MySQL rows efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, performance, post

I have a VB .Net application which receives/sends data through PHP POST method to update/get rows from a MySQL database using HTTPWebRequest. My host does not allow remote database access, so I think this is the only way I can go about doing this.. but how do I do it efficiently?

I'm worried that my method is most probably very inefficient.

For sending data, what I'm currently doing is adding all data to be sent to a string like:

```
&colA=valA1;valA2;valA3&colB=valB1;valB2;valB3 etc...
```

That string gets sent through HTTPWebRequest to the PHP file every X minutes, then the PHP file splits the rows into arrays (row 0 = valA1, valB1) to add/update the db with an sql query in a for loop.

Then for retrieving data, I'm doing something similar - getting all rows from the db and adding columns to string split by ";". My .Net application reads the string and splits it, and adds the rows to arrays. The retrieval of data is only done once when the application is started.

Is there a more efficient method? Is it better to send multiple POST requests, or a POST request containing all the rows? Should I limit the amount of rows that get sent at a time? (There are roughly 1000 rows, and about 20 columns per row)

---

Edit:

```
if($_POST['action'] == "queryGroup" && $_POST['group'] != ""){
    $result = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT forename, surname, dob FROM accounts WHERE group='".$_POST['group']."'");
    $output = "";
    foreach($result as $row){
        $output .= $row['forename'].";".$row['surname'].";".$row['dob']."|";
    }
    echo(substr($output, 0, -1)); //Remove the last instance of '|'
}
```

So in the VB .Net application, I would split '|' to make an array of individual accounts.

Then split ';' to get the forename/surname/dob of each account.

There are other rows which are more variable - Like a status check (Online/Offline) and a timer for last activity etc, and new users can be added from the VB .Net application.. which is why the rows are updated every now and then.

I have a class which is used for making the WebRequest, WebResponse and StreamReader objects which is used with:

```
Dim post As New POST
With post
    .URL = "http://www.host.com/post.php"
    .Data = "action=queryGroup&group=" & Group
    .Connect() 'Sends the WebRequest

    Lst(.Response) 'Gets the WebResponse and adds it to a StreamReader and sends to Lst function
End With

Private Sub Lst(ByVal response As String)
    Dim accounts As String() = Nothing
    accounts = response.Split(CChar("|"))

    For i = 0 To accounts.Count - 1
        Dim arr As String() = accounts(i).Split(CChar(";"))
        arrAdd(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2)) 'arrAdd puts all the data into a ListView
    Next
End Sub
```

Then for sending the data.. it's the same sort of thing but in reverse.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to know what is right/wrong, efficient/inefficient without knowing the context of what is happening or why.  POSTing that much data seems like a weird method, but not knowing your context or application I would say just make sure your PHP INI settings are set up to handle large POST data and won't timeout on you.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't have the code with me at the time so couldn't recall from memory what I had. But I've edited the post with pretty much the method I'm using at the moment. Is there much impact on the server when sending such large POST queries?

Comment: If we're being honest I've never attempted POST's with so much data. I'd be curious myself. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your only allowed to make port 80 (or better port 443) connections, this is i think indeed the way to go. As for issues, you might want to check your php.ini `post_max_size`, it is the maximum allowed uploaded size for a post. As for script processing, look at `set_time_limit`, the maximum time for a script to execute. Other then that is about how your script is handling events.

If your host does allow SOCKS, you can also set up a proxy server and connect in that way directly to your database. See http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1822-PHP-TCP-connection-wrapper-using-SOCKS-5-protocol.html for the SOCKS 5 wrapper. I've never used it, but you might want to check it out.